# 9-patch images in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, nine-patch

Do 9-patch images work inside an Android WebView? I haven't found anything that definitively answers it one way or another. I know there's a project that uses Javascript to mimic it on the web (https://github.com/chrislondon/9-Patch-Image-for-Websites), so I figure to use that as a workable alternative but wondered if anyone else had ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is feasible and there are several ways that we could have a try.

1. Do it in js/css. Just as you mentioned, there are several js plugin that support parsing 9patch. And css3 also has a new feature named border-image, which could achieve the same result.
2. Do it in android. If it is only used in android, we can use `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()` and enable js to invoke android code. When javascript want a image, it send the image uri and desired size of the image to android. Android try to load the image and use `NinePatchDrawable` to parse it. Convert it to a bitmap and return back.